# A tkinter canvas doesn´t show the image

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas, python-imaging-library

i have this code:

```
    def soltar(self, event):
     directorio = event.data
     directorio = directorio.replace("{","")
     directorio = directorio.replace("}","")
     img = Image.open(str(directorio))
     raw = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
     self.canvas.config(width=img.width, height=img.height, bg='white')
     self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=raw, anchor='nw')
```

soltar is the function what ocurs when the user drop a file (image) into the canvas called "canvas" defined at the start of the program with TkinterDnD library. The size of the canvas changes when i drop a image but the canvas doest show it, no error or warnings. Thanks.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the image data around. Try setting it as a field rather than a local variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to the image data around somewhere to stop python dropping it. Either set it as a field on your class or add it as an attribute of the canvas as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230708073556/https://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) (wayback machine link as page is now dead).

```
def soltar(self, event):
     directorio = event.data
     directorio = directorio.replace("{","")
     directorio = directorio.replace("}","")
     img = Image.open(str(directorio))
     raw = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
     self.canvas.config(width=img.width, height=img.height, bg='white')
     self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=raw, anchor='nw')
     self.canvas._image_data = raw # <-- here
```